# Truncate text to fit table cell without wrapping using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want the text in one of the columns of a table to not wrap, but to just truncate so that it fits within the **current** size of the table cell. I don't want the table cell to change size, as I need the table to be exactly `100%` the width of the container.

This is because the table with `100%` width is inside of a positioned `div` with overflow: auto (it's actually inside of a jQuery `UI.Layout` panel).

I tried both `overflow: hidden` and the text still wrapped. I tried `white-space: nowrap`, but it stretched the table wider than `100%` and added a horizontal scroll bar.

```
div.container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  /* user can slide resize bars to change the width & height */
  width: 600px;  
  height: 300px;
}
table { width: 100% }
td.nowrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>From</td>
      <td>Subject</td>
      <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob Smith</td>
      <td class="nowrap">
        <strong>Message subject</strong>
        <span>This is a preview of the message body and could be long.</span>
      </td>
      <td>2010-03-30 02:18AM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way using **CSS** to solve this? If I had a fixed table cell size, then `overflow:hidden` would truncate anything that flows over, but I can't used a fixed size as I want the table to stretch with the `UI.Layout` panel size.

If not, then how would I solve this with jQuery?

My use case is similar to the Gmail interface, where an email subject is bolded and the beginning of the message body is shown, but then truncated to fit.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite old but here is my answer.

```
table { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCC7s/)

Comment: This works _in addition to_ setting the td style= `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this on the span tag inside td

```
display: block;
word-break: break-all;
```

(*late but might help someone else*)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the cell size in *pixels*, you can simply use *percentages*:

```
td.nowrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 60%;  /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: @RegDwight: I certainly tried this, both assigning widths via css and directly in the html. But in each case the table would still expand wider than 100% and I'd get a horiz scrollbar.